# AWS eb create fails - user is not authorized to perform: autoscaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

I am using aws to deploy my project. I have installed eb cli and on running eb create and choosing defaults for options the project is uploaded to S3:

```
Uploading udagram-myuser-dev/app-200712_154053.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
Environment details for: udagram-myuser-dev-dev4
  Application name: udagram-myuser-dev
  Region: us-east-1
  Deployed Version: app-200712_154053
  Environment ID: e-kjqwp5hmec
  Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1::platform/Node.js 12 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/5.1.0
  Tier: WebServer-Standard-1.0
  CNAME: udagram-myuser-dev-dev4.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
  Updated: 2020-07-12 13:40:59.026000+00:00
```

But, I get errors:

```
Printing Status:
2020-07-12 13:40:57    INFO    createEnvironment is starting.
2020-07-12 13:40:59    INFO    Using elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-087232098494 as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
2020-07-12 13:41:19    INFO    Created target group named: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:087232098494:targetgroup/awseb-AWSEB-5K4TX808XT7/debd1eceb7173e02
2020-07-12 13:41:19    INFO    Created security group named: sg-02b8b3f3c5a3f0980
2020-07-12 13:41:35    INFO    Created security group named: awseb-e-kjqwp5hmec-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-DR1EWHJA2HMS
2020-07-12 13:41:50    ERROR   Stack named 'awseb-e-kjqwp5hmec-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED'  Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBV2LoadBalancer, AWSEBAutoScalingGroup]. 
2020-07-12 13:41:50    ERROR   Creating Auto Scaling group failed Reason: API: autoscaling:CreateAutoScalingGroup User: arn:aws:iam::087232098494:user/udagram-myuser-dev is not authorized to perform: autoscaling:CreateAutoScalingGroup on resource: arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:087232098494:autoScalingGroup:*:autoScalingGroupName/awseb-e-kjqwp5hmec-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1D5XFNTTBU9AM with an explicit deny
2020-07-12 13:41:50    ERROR   Creating load balancer named: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:087232098494:loadbalancer/app/awseb-AWSEB-2RDS14S53WYD/615ad3ef19b80f90 failed Reason: Resource creation cancelled
2020-07-12 13:41:52    INFO    Launched environment: udagram-myuser-dev-dev4. However, there were issues during launch. See event log for details.
                                
ERROR: ServiceError - Launched environment: udagram-myuser-dev-dev4. However, there were issues during launch. See event log for details.
```

I don't know why I get this error, since myuser has `AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess` attached as a policy in permissions in IAM.
On running eb status --verbose, I get:

```
INFO: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myuser/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/aws.py", line 212, in make_api_call
    response_data = operation(**operation_options)
  File "/Users/myuser/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 316, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/myuser/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 626, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.LoadBalancerNotFoundException: An error occurred (LoadBalancerNotFound) when calling the DescribeTargetGroups operation: Load balancer 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:087232098494:loadbalancer/app/awseb-AWSEB-ULG8J44BG8P3/8d3169781c72a079' not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myuser/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/elbv2.py", line 62, in get_target_groups_for_load_balancer
    LoadBalancerArn=load_balancer_arn
  File "/Users/myuser/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/elbv2.py", line 24, in _make_api_call
    return aws.make_api_call('elbv2', operation_name, **operation_options)
  File "/Users/myuser/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/aws.py", line 221, in make_api_call
    _handle_response_code(e.response, attempt, aggregated_error_message)
  File "/Users/myuser/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/aws.py", line 275, in _handle_response_code
    raise error
ebcli.objects.exceptions.ServiceError: Load balancer 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:087232098494:loadbalancer/app/awseb-AWSEB-ULG8J44BG8P3/8d3169781c72a079' not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myuser/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ebcli/core/ebrun.py", line 62, in run_app
    app.run()
  File "/Users/myuser/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cement/core/foundation.py", line 797, in run
    return_val = self.controller._dispatch()
  File "/Users/myuser/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cement/core/controller.py", line 472, in _dispatch
    return func()
  File "/Users/myuser/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cement/core/controller.py", line 478, in _dispatch
    return func()
  File "/Users/myuser/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ebcli/core/abstractcontroller.py", line 92, in default
    self.do_command()
  File "/Users/myuser/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ebcli/controllers/status.py", line 30, in do_command
    statusops.status(app_name, env_name, verbose)
  File "/Users/myuser/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ebcli/operations/statusops.py", line 130, in status
    _print_information_about_elb_and_instances(env_name) if verbose else None
  File "/Users/myuser/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ebcli/operations/statusops.py", line 190, in _print_information_about_elb_and_instances
    _print_elbv2_health_stats(load_balancer_name, instances)
  File "/Users/myuser/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ebcli/operations/statusops.py", line 197, in _print_elbv2_health_stats
    in elbv2.get_target_groups_for_load_balancer(load_balancer_name)
  File "/Users/myuser/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/elbv2.py", line 65, in get_target_groups_for_load_balancer
    raise NotFoundError(e)
ebcli.objects.exceptions.NotFoundError: Load balancer 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:087232098494:loadbalancer/app/awseb-AWSEB-ULG8J44BG8P3/8d3169781c72a079' not found
```

I have following AWS managed default policies: **Administrator access**, **AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess** and **IAMUserChangePassword**, as well as a custom group policy attached:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetAccessPoint",
                "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListAccessPoints",
                "s3:ListJobs",
                "s3:CreateJob",
                "s3:HeadBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::udagram-myuser-dev/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::udagram-myuser-dev"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What do I need to do be able to deploy successfully to aws?

Comment: Other than this policy do you have others attached, it seems to indicate there is an explicit deny.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/854143/iam-user-is-not-authorized-to-perform-application-autoscalingdescribescalablet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**

The account is part of a course, the likely reason is that a service control policy is denying access to specific services.

**Original**

The error message indicates that the user has been explicitly denied access to perform this action.

```
is not authorized to perform: autoscaling:CreateAutoScalingGroup on resource: with an explicit deny
```

You need to review other policies attached and remove the **deny statement** that is explicitly blocking the access.

With AWS permissions adding a deny statement will always ovrride over permissions even if you have added allow statements.

For more information on policy evaluations take a look at the [Policy Evaluation Logic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html#policy-eval-denyallow) page.

Comment: I have updated the question with all the policies that are attached to my user

Comment: Does your user have a permissions boundary, or does your account have a service control policy placed on it?

Comment: I don't have permissions boundary set, and I am not sure where to check service control policy

Comment: This would be if your account is in an organisation within the master account

Comment: My account is within vocareum, I am doing a course through them

Comment: Right, they probably have a service control policy attached to your account to prevent specific actions then (such as autoscaling). If you believe it should be allowed you'll need to contact them :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could assist